# Chevy cavalier 1999 hot rod hot wired radiator fan

Tags: chevrolet, cooling-system, radiator, fan, cavalier

Long story short I have a chevy cavalier with a hot wired radiator fan and I noticed my car stays cooler in the winter.will my car be fine or a should I install a aftermarket thermostat for the custom fan.

Comment: Hot wired? It would be simpler to disconnect in winter than add more home-made stuff.

Comment: Or add a manual switch.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If your Chevy uses a coolant sensor to send temperature signals to the pcm, it may have failed. The temperature gauge may be displaying incorrectly too when it depends on the coolant sensor sending correct signals to the pcm to drive the gauge. An alternate radiator fan switch can be the variable temperature sensor with its probe inserted into the radiator. The adjustable temperature dial customizes turn on/off  temp.